# Text search using python

Tags: python, textblob

I am working on a text search project, and using text blob to search for sentences from text.
TextBlob pulls all the sentences with the keywords efficiently. However for effective research i also want to pull out one sentence before and one after which I am unable to figure.

Below is the code I am using:

```
def extraxt_sents(Text,word):
    search_words = set(word.split(','))
        sents = ''.join([s.lower() for s in Text])
        blob = TextBlob(sents)
    matches = [str(s) for s in blob.sentences if search_words & set(s.words)]
    print search_words
    print(matches)
```

Comment: Is there some indent mistakes in your code?

Comment: i suggest, take look at 'nltk'

Comment: @cengizkrbck TextBlob seems to work better than nltk. I a,a not able to figure the one sentence before and one after.

Comment: Try using indices: `[map(str, blob.sentences[i-1:i+2]) for i, s in enumerate(blob.sentences) if search_words & set(s.words)]`

Comment: @tobias_k I am getting a list of list and i need to write an excel files with the output. Can you amend the code to get a list??

Comment: @RaghavShaligram What exactly do you mean? Do you want to flatten the list, i.e. instead of `[(prev1, match1, next1), (prev2, match2, next2), ...]` get `[prev1, match1, next1, prev2, match2, next2, ...]`?

Comment: @tobias_k yes..since i have to iterate over the list and write it to an excel file

Comment: I wrote a .join and iterated over the list and joined the sentences to be written to an excel file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the lines before and after the match, you can either create a loop and memorize the previous line, or use [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation), like `[from:to]` on the `blob.sentences` list.

The best way might be to use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) bultin function.

```
match_region = [map(str, blob.sentences[i-1:i+2])     # from prev to after next
                for i, s in enumerate(blob.sentences) # i is index, e is element
                if search_words & set(s.words)]       # same as your condition
```

Here, `blob.sentences[i-1:i+2]` will extract the sublist spanning from index `i-1` (inclusive) to index `i+2` (exclusive), and `map` turns the elements in this list into strings.

*Note:* Actually, you might want to replace `i-1` with `max(0, i-1)`; otherwise `i-1` could be `-1` and Python would interpret this as the last element, yielding an empty slice. If `i+2` is higher than the list's length, on the other hand, this will not be a problem.